# Fetch record from current week

Tags: mysql

Only need to fetch record of current week. Created Column format is '`2013-11-13 00:00:00`'

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS con 
FROM  `accounts` 
WHERE  `description` LIKE  '%Earned%'   AND created = __________
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [YEARWEEK()](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/24992)

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS con 
FROM  `accounts` 
WHERE  `description` LIKE  '%Earned%'   
AND yearweek(created) = yearweek(curdate())
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/24992)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS con 
FROM  `accounts` 
WHERE  `description` LIKE  '%Earned%'   AND
WEEK(created) = WEEK(curdate()) AND 
YEAR(created) = YEAR(curdate())
```